# Django model as part of Ajax response

Tags: python, django, json, serialization, model

I want to put a Django model in de response for my Ajax request. Currently I have this in my views.py:

```
def get_account(request, account_id):

    try:
        account = Account.objects.get(pk=account_id)
        success = True
        error_message = None
    except Account.DoesNotExist:
        success = False
        error_message = 'This account does not exist'

    results = {
        'success': success,
        'error_message': error_message,
    }

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(results),
        mimetype='application/json')
```

I would like to add the `account` model to the `results` dict. `account.__dict__` won't do because it will have references to other objects in it.

I found de [django serialize function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/serialization/), which serializes it exactly how I want it, only it makes a Json string directly, so I'll end up with a Json string inside a Json object (bad for bandwith if you have large models, because the Json string get's escaped all over). So then I would need to json_decode it another time in Javascript.

Also, the django serialize function only accepts lists of objects, so I would have to make a list with only one object, and when I unserialize it take the first value of the list (which isn't a super big problem, but it adds up to the pile).

It would be great if you could serialize a model to just a python dict. Then you can do anything with it as you like.

Anyone ever got the same problem? How did you solve it?

Comment: Consider using a proper API module such as http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/

Comment: An API for internal usage? Isn't that overkill? Or is it commonly used?

Comment: I didn't notice this is for internal usage, sorry. Consider the API anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Daniel's answer I was able to do it:

```
def get_account_data(account):
    fields = serializers.serialize('python', [account, ])[0]['fields']
    return {field: str(fields[field]) for field in fields}
```

Because I'm sending it over Ajax, I needed everything to be a string. If you serialize using the 'python' method, some things like a datetime field will have a function in it (like `datetime.date(2012, 12, 23)`). This function makes a dict with only string values.

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize to a Python dict and pass that to be converted to JSON:

```
qs_as_dict = serializers.serialize('python', qs)
results['objects'] = qs_as_dict
```

Comment: Hey, that's pretty cool! Didn't know you could serialize to a python dict (can't find it in the docs). With this information I was able to find a solution (see my answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

instead of returning a model object, why don't you just return the desired values you required in response?

```
results.update({'account': {'id': account.id, 'title': account.title}})
```

Comment: That's a possibility, however it can be a lot of work if you have a large model, or if you need to do it on multiple models, and every time you change your model you should change the Ajax response too.

Comment: I don't agree. Lets suppose if you able to return the model. and later you change the model you still have to update the method you have used on front end. And usually there is not much information is required to send back in ajax calls.

Comment: You have a point. Maybe I should write my responses more to the requirements of my calls. I just like to make things abstract most of the times.